# Question about the Third Derivative

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Take a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that it has a
continuous third derivative. I would like to show that there exists a point
$a$ such that
$$f(a)\cdot f'(a) \cdot f''(a) \cdot f'''(a) \geq 0$$

I had imagined that we could start this proof by assuming for the sake of
contradiction that $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}.
f(a) \cdot f'(a) \cdot f''(a) \cdot f'''(a) < 0.$
This would imply that

1. $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}. f(a) \neq 0 \wedge f'(a) \neq 0 \wedge
   f''(a) \neq 0 \wedge f'''(a) \neq 0.$
2. In the function set $\{f,f',f'',f'''\},$ there are either three elements in
   this set that are strictly positive when evaluated at $a$ or three elements in
   this set that are strictly negative when evaluated at $a$.

The first implication presents a meaningful implication: The ranges for every
function in the set $\{f,f',f'',f'''\}$ does not contain $0$. Now, I would
imagine that for continuity purposes, does this mean that for each function in
the set $\{f,f',f'',f'''\}$, the range is either a subset of
all strictly negative values of the real number line
or a subset of all non-negative values of the real number line? If so, what
might that do to contract the second implications? Any suggestions would be
appreciated.

Comment: Aw darn, $f(x)=\sqrt x$ was a nice candidate, but it does not accept negative values.